# ng g app-shell input.mergeMap is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I am trying to use the latest angular cli to generate a component. I tried to generate a module also I got a similar error.

```
ng g component testComponent
```

I got this error

```
input.mergeMap is not a function
TypeError: input.mergeMap is not a function
    at Object.callRule (C:\Users\dammy\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Cars\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\rules\call.js:70:18)
```

my Package.json file looks like this:

```
{
 ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
```

I have installed: Angular/cli@1.6.0

Comment: I am running into the same issue as well. I am using 1.6.0

Comment: I changed "rxjs": "5.5.2" to "rxjs": "^5.5.2" in my package.json file and that seemed to have fixed the issue. I dug through the call.js file and found out that they are relying mergeMap that's part of 'rxjs'. Please try it and let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I have rxjs 5.5.5 installed and am still getting this error.

Comment: @MapLion updated also still getting the same error

Comment: @NetEmmanuel I was able to resolve it with the answer I gave below; make sure both your global and local typescripts and cli's are in sync in terms of version and make sure your rxjs is 5.5.5; it may help to remove everything first and start fresh.

Comment: Try this it worked for me "npm remove @angular/cli --save". This will remove the local angular cli installation. My "rxjs" was "5.4.2" and I cange it to "rxjs": "^5.4.2". Remove the node_modules folder inside the project and run npm install again. Hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
It seems that if you have @angular/cli installed globally and a different 
version installed locally it gets broken. I solved the same error removing the 
cli package that was installed locally with 

npm remove @angular/cli --save 

then install your CLI->

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: This Solved the problem for me. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For me, i re-installed angular-devkit. Run the command:

`npm install @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 --save-dev`

And it worked !

Comment: Those versions work together well: "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6" and "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.39"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when upgrading to the `@angular/cli` 1.6.0 even though I had `rxjs` v5.5.5.  I was able to resolve it by doing the following:

`npm i --save-dev @angular/cli@^1.6.0`

`npm i @angular/cli@^1.6.0 -g`

`npm i --save-dev typescript@^2.6.2`

`npm i typescript@^2.6.2 -g`

In my case, it was most likely caused by my global typescript not being the same version as my local typescript. I just reinstalled all to make sure everything was in sync [and obviously, you can combine some of these commands, I just posted it like this for clarity].

UPDATE:  I had this problem return for some reason and the above solutions didn't work by themselves this time around.  After attempting the above, I was able to resolve it by deleting my `package-lock.json` and local node_modules folder and doing another `npm install`.

Comment: This [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8782) has a variety of solutions for people, but @MapLion's suggestion seems to align with what worked for most.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that version of `@angular/cli` has an `rxjs` dependency of v5.5.5

See this dependency tree:

```
yarn list rxjs
yarn list v0.27.5
├─ @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.41
│  └─ rxjs@5.5.5
├─ @angular/cli@1.6.0
│  └─ rxjs@5.5.5
└─ rxjs@5.5.2
Done in 1.16s.
```

In my case the version was at 5.5.2 and upgrading fixed this issue.

Comment: updating rxjs to 5.5.5 doesn't fix this for me

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue; I've temporarily reverted to v1.5.0 of @angular/cli by deleting node_modules and ran `yarn install` again.

Upgrading @angular/cli to version 1.6.0 introduces this issue due to dependencies mismatch for @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.41 (requires rxjs@5.5.5) and @angular/cli@1.6.0.

**Edit:** Notice that setting the version of rxjs to 5.5.5 in your package.json does not upgrade the code dependencies for  @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.41 or @angular/cli@1.6.0 as shown in the extract below.

Reference: [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8782][1]

Commands affected: 
`ng generate XXX`

Seems the dependencies for @angular/cli and @angular-devkit/schematics are not upgraded after upgrading @angular/cli to v1.6.0 and particularly rxjs is not upgraded.

```
├─ @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.41
│  ├─ @angular-devkit/core@0.0.22
│  ├─ @ngtools/json-schema@^1.1.0
│  ├─ @schematics/schematics@0.0.10
│  ├─ minimist@^1.2.0
│  ├─ rxjs@^5.5.2
│  ├─ rxjs@5.5.2
│  │  └─ symbol-observable@^1.0.1
│  └─ symbol-observable@1.0.4
├─ @angular/animations@5.0.2
│  └─ tslib@^1.7.1
├─ @angular/cli@1.6.0
│  ├─ @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@~0.0.35
│  ├─ @angular-devkit/schematics@~0.0.40
│  ├─ @ngtools/json-schema@1.1.0
│  ├─ @ngtools/webpack@1.9.0
│  ├─ @schematics/angular@~0.1.10
│  ├─ autoprefixer@^6.5.3
│  ├─ chalk@~2.2.0
│  ├─ chalk@2.2.2
│  │  ├─ ansi-styles@^3.1.0
│  │  ├─ escape-string-regexp@^1.0.5
│  │  └─ supports-color@^4.0.0
│  ├─ circular-dependency-plugin@^4.2.1
│  ├─ common-tags@^1.3.1
│  ├─ copy-webpack-plugin@^4.1.1
│  ├─ core-object@^3.1.0
│  ├─ css-loader@^0.28.1
│  ├─ cssnano@^3.10.0
│  ├─ denodeify@^1.2.1
│  ├─ ember-cli-string-utils@^1.0.0
│  ├─ exports-loader@^0.6.3
│  ├─ extract-text-webpack-plugin@^3.0.2
│  ├─ file-loader@^1.1.5
│  ├─ fs-extra@^4.0.0
│  ├─ glob@^7.0.3
│  ├─ html-webpack-plugin@^2.29.0
│  ├─ istanbul-instrumenter-loader@^2.0.0
│  ├─ karma-source-map-support@^1.2.0
│  ├─ less-loader@^4.0.5
│  ├─ less@^2.7.2
│  ├─ license-webpack-plugin@^1.0.0
│  ├─ lodash@^4.11.1
│  ├─ memory-fs@^0.4.1
│  ├─ minimatch@^3.0.4
│  ├─ node-modules-path@^1.0.0
│  ├─ node-sass@^4.3.0
│  ├─ nopt@^4.0.1
│  ├─ opn@~5.1.0
│  ├─ portfinder@~1.0.12
│  ├─ postcss-custom-properties@^6.1.0
│  ├─ postcss-loader@^2.0.8
│  ├─ postcss-url@^7.1.2
│  ├─ raw-loader@^0.5.1
│  ├─ resolve@^1.1.7
│  ├─ rxjs@^5.5.2
│  ├─ rxjs@5.5.2
│  │  └─ symbol-observable@^1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to @angular/cli 1.6.3 and typescript 2.6.2. You have to check if both global and local versions of @angular/cli and Typescript are the same.

You can check the global versions with this commands:

```
ng -v
tsc -v
```

Then compare it with your local package.json.

If they differs:

**Globally**

```
npm remove -g @angular/cli
npm remove -g typescript

npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
npm i -g typescript@latest
```

**Locally:**

```
//Remove node_modules folder
//remove package-lock.json
npm i @angular/cli@latest --save-dev
npm i typescript@latest --save-dev
npm install
```

**NOTE:** at the time of writing I´m getting a warning from angular cli informing that

```
@angular/compiler-cli@5.2.0 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.6.0' but 2.6.2 was found instead.
```

If you want to avoid this. You can use

```
npm i -g typescript@2.4.2
npm i typescript@2.4.2 --save-dev
```